# Why is my dataframe dropping a coulmn once i do a groupby?(The column that is dropping is one of the columns that im using to group)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame with 5 columns and some values:

```
df=pd.Dataframe({'date':['2019-02-07',2019-02-07','2019-02-08'],
                 'id':[223,223,223],
                 'code':[1234,1234,1234],
                 'value':[4234,34534,23423],
                 'qty':[2,3,4]})
```

So now im doing a groupby with the following key columns:

```
key_col=['date','id','code']
df=df.groupby(key_col).agg({'value':'sum', 'qty':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now by doing this, the new 'df' that i get drops the id column but gives me the rest. Why is it doing that and do i retain that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing that because you pass `drop=True` to `reset_index`, which dictates that you want to discard the index. Remove it, then the index will become usual columns.

```
df=df.groupby(key_col).agg({'value':'sum', 'qty':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

On the other note, you can just pass `as_index=False` to `groupby()` and forgo the `reset_index`:

```
df=df.groupby(key_col, as_index=False).agg({'value':'sum', 'qty':'sum'})
```

and then the output would be:

```
         date   id  code  value  qty
0  2019-02-07  223  1234  38768    5
1  2019-02-08  223  1234  23423    4
```